# How to Prevent Onchange triggering on page load

Tags: jquery

Although not a new question on SO i have not found a way to do this when an argument is passed into a function. Presently i have this which is erroneously triggering on page load :

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#advtracks', function() {
        filterMarkers( $(this).val() );
});
```

I read the answer is to use syntax, without parenthisis, to prevent calling it on page load:

```
$("#advtracks").on('change', filterMarkers);
```

However how do i call filterMarkers with the argument:

```
$(this).val()
```

I need to do this way as the errant call onload is preventing my jQuery/Bootstrap datepicker plugins fron initialising on load.

With thanks

Comment: Try attaching the event listener once the page has finished loading

Comment: how would i do that from jquery??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use document ready event of jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '#advtracks', function() {
        filterMarkers(this.value);
    });
});
```

[**$( document ).ready()**](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Couple of other things.

1. Instead of using `select#advtracks` selector, you can simply use `#advtracks`
2. `$(this).val()` can be replaced with `this.value`

Comment: Yes!! Big thanks both solved the problem - will remember this as its been bothersome in the post - Sweet!

Comment: Bhai Tu mujhe bacha liya..from 2 days I m banging head..U r my angel..I m emotional now.Thank you..God bless you

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass the argument `$(this).val()` explicitly . When you invoke an external function during an event, the scope of the element on which the event was triggered is automatically visible inside that external function.

```
$("#advtracks").on('change', filterMarkers);

function filterMarkers()
{
  alert($(this).val()); // gives the selected value 
}
```

Here's an example : http://fiddle.jshell.net/brxu8w8m/2/

Comment: Indeed -  i will keep this fact in mind, though i usually use the old-school method as i frequently do more than just grab the val() - so its more convenient - still nothing wrong with having more knowledge under your belt - cheers